# Popping Out of Hidden Overflow without using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, absolute

Let say we have the following html structure

```
<div class="overflow box">
  <div class="position-relative list-items">
    <div class="position-absolute show-on-hover">
  </div>
  <div class="position-relative list-items">
    <div class="position-absolute show-on-hover">
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="position-relative list-items">
    <div class="position-absolute show-on-hover">
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that main box(container) has `overflow: hidden scroll` to hold partuclar number of elements inside and show scroll when number is big enough. When `hover` on any inside `div`, `absolute`-ly positioned and displayed `none` elements should appear and stick to their respective parents, positioned `relative`.

Desired outcome looks like this:

[image: desired state]

However, we see this:

[image]

I found [one solution](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) which is to use javacript for calculating position of the parent div (`position: relative`) on each hover and thus adjust `top` and `left` properties for hover div.

Is there any possible way to visually break out of `overflow` only using CSS? Maybe some rearrangements of the structure or some CSS tweaks.

Comment: Why can't you use Javascript though?

Comment: @jom Sure I can. Just wanted to know whether there is another solution to the problem. CSS approach is more preferable for me, if there is.